# Is it important to include bootstrap CDN link?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Ive been designing a custom bootstrap theme by making

1. My own styles main.css and menu.css
2. by over-riding some bootstrap default styles in the pre-made bootstrap.css

I have a link for the CDN

```
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

and was wondering if it was important to include this link and what exactly is it doing ?
When the page loads the link it overwrites my styles... Was just curious thanks.

Comment: *"When the page loads the link it overwrites my styles... "* Did you try swapping the links so this one is loaded first?

Comment: put the link to your custom styles after the bootstrap one, and yours will take precedence.

Comment: _by over-riding some bootstrap default styles_. So yes you have to include it.

Comment: Well if you want to _override_ Bootstrap styles, you should include Bootstrap, and then include your styles, period.

Answer (score 0):

Reviewed the comments and did away with CDN link, only kept local version

```
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- menu styles-->
    <link href="css/menu.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- overall styles -->
    <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: But you don't need to include both the cdn and the local version of bootstrap - one copy of the file would do.